# OpenCv - cv2.VideoWriter object has no attribute release

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I am using OpenCV with python 2.7.3 on Linux 64-bit machine. I wanted to fetch frames from my Logitech C270 and store it as an AVI video. The code is working fine, it also shows me the video getting captured and the output file is also created. But when i try to play the file it is not playing at all as well as i am getting 'cv2.VideoWriter object has no attribute release' error on terminal. So, if someone can tell me how to release the cv2.VideoWriter after completion.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0,(640,480))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if cap.isOpened() == 0:
        cap.open(1)

    if ret==True:

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        out.write(gray)
        cv2.imshow('frame',gray)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I'm sad to see no answers here, as I'm now having the same problem.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the lines below:

```
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0,(640,480))
```

Use those one:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (int(cap.get(3)),int(cap.get(4))))
```

I think, this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using this line

```
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D')
```

Use this one

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
```